# Dont work AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I need to do notification at the specified date. I have MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //if only it all is working.But me need notification at 12:12:00 PM 19.10.15
    //Utils.generateNotification(getApplicationContext());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //set notification for date --> 19th Oct 2015 at 12:12:00 PM
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 19);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

and MyReceiver

```
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    /*Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
     context.startService(service1);*/
    Log.i("App", "called receiver method");
    try{
        Utils.generateNotification(context);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and some class with notifiation it work.

```
public class Utils {

public static NotificationManager mManager;

public static void generateNotification(Context context){ 

    mManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "AlarmManagerDemo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);
    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
              android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

What is wrong?
Recommend how else can i realize notification a specified time.
P.S. The best English :) sry

LINK:
[Hyperlink(Project)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2WYH-ZKqg6QmZWM3h5Xy04eWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: not show messages(Notification)

Comment: Did you try flipping the month and day of month variables. Looks like they are backwards.

Comment: I made this mistake when prepared the code for publication

Comment: I even tried System.currentTimeMillis()+4000(and any value) but dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your receiver is set to only fire the notification on reboot. Go ahead and change it to this.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" />
```

Setting an intent filter singles out how the receiver will be able to be fired.

[More on intent-filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: my answer such as one of the other answers.. 
its dont work for me :( if you can help me. I added hyperlink(At the end of the main post) for my project

Answer (score 1):

Look at this

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
              android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

did you enabled `MyReceiver` receiver 
Enable it by removing this `android:enabled="false"` or in code enable it like this

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, MyReceiver.class);
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: its dont work for me :( if you can help me. I added hyperlink(At the end of the main post) for my project